# Indent a markdown list item?

Tags: indentation, filetype-markdown

I am frequently editing markdown files, and when dealing with multi-line items in hierarchical lists, it would be great to have a rapid way to indent or un-indent a list item.  For example, how can I most easily indent the longest multi-line list item in the following text?

```
- Some list item
- Another list item that is long and so
  is split onto multiple lines
  that are more
  than I want to have to count
  or select manually
  - A sub-list item that is also
    split onto multiple lines
```

If the list items were empty-line-separated then of course I could use `>ap` but as it is I am using `5>>` which involves counting, and of course I have to be at the first line of the list item to use it.

Is there a better way?

(Note: I am mostly allergic to plugins.)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try defining a custom object `li` for list item. This way you could operate on it with any operator including `>`.

A way to do that is to define a visual mapping with `:xnoremap` which selects your object.
Then you would define your list item object with `:onoremap li :normal vli<CR>`.
The `:onoremap` mapping would tell Vim that whenever you hit `li` after an operator, it would be the same as if you were in visual mode and had selected your object with the motion `li`.

---

For example, let's say you want to create the object `i_` for `inside underscores` to operate on `bar` in `foo_bar_baz`. You could include this in your `vimrc`:

```
xnoremap i_ T_ot_
onoremap i_ :normal vi_<CR>
```

Here the `{rhs}` of the `:xnoremap` mapping is `T_ot_`, which is a motion which should select the text between 2 consecutive underscores on the same line.

```
T_    move the left-hand side of the visual selection until the previous underscore
o     give the focus to the other side of the selection
t_    move the right-hand side of the selection until the next underscore
```

Now to delete, change, yank or select the text between the two surrounding underscores, you could type `di_`, `ci_`, `yi_`, `vi_`.

---

In your case, it's more complex because you don't want to operate on the text between 2 consecutive underscores but between 2 consecutive lines beginning with a dash.

So the tricky part would be the `{rhs}` of the visual mapping which selects your object.

Here's a possible implementation, which is not very robust but seems to work on the simple example you provided:

```
xnoremap <silent> li :<C-U>call <SID>ListItem()<CR>
onoremap <silent> li :normal vli<CR>

function! s:ListItem() abort
    if search('^\s*-', 'bcW') != 0
        call search('\v.\n\s*(-|$)', 'sW')
        normal! v``
    endif
endfunction
```

It's the same thing as before, except this time the motion is managed by a function: `ListItem()`.

The function looks backward for the pattern `^\s*-`:

```
^     beginning of line
\s*   zero or more whitespace
-     a dash
```

If it finds something it then looks for the pattern `\v^\s*(-|$)`:

```
\v       very magic mode
.        any character except a newline
\n       a newline
\s*      zero or more whitespace
(-|$)    a dash or an end of line
```

The `search()` function can be used with several flags, here there are:

```
b    look backwards instead of forward
c    accept a match at current cursor position
s    set the mark ' before jumping to the match
W    don't wrap around the end of the file
```

The last command in the function ``` normal! v`` ``` is responsible for selecting the object:

```
v      go into visual mode
``     move the left-hand side of the selection to the location before
       the last search (to the beginning of the item)
```

---

I don't think it's very robust, for example if your cursor is after the last item, hitting `vli` shouldn't select anything. But here, it will select the last item anyway. To solve this, the regexes passed to the `search()` function should be tweaked.
For example, the first one should not match a `^\s*-` if there's an empty line between it and the current cursor position.

Still, it seems to work on your example by hitting `>li` while the cursor is in any of the 3 items, without the need to count the number of lines or to be at the beginning of the item. So maybe it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

How about

`nnoremap <Leader>f ?^\s*\-\\|\%^<CR>V/\n^\s*\-\\|\%$<CR>`

which would allow you to use `<Leader>f` to select the item your cursor is in in visual mode, so you can use `>` indent further? Of course you could easily integrate the indent into the keypress, but you'd need another remap to decrease the indentation level.

I assume you know the basics, here's what the regexps do:

- `?^\s*\-\\|\%^` searches backwards for the next line that starts with whitespaces and a dash, or the start of the file (`\\|` for the logical OR, and `\%^` for the beginning of the file)
- `/\n^\s*\-\\|\%$` searches for a newline (`\n`) followed the a line as above, and if that isn't found, go to the end of the file (`\\|` for the logical OR, and `\%$` for the end of the file)

It has a rough edge, namely if you're on a dash itself, that follows only whitespaces, which works if the dash is indented itself, but if the dash is on column 1 it selects the previous entry.

Still though, imho it works good enough if you don't like a plugin, and since it only selects, you can easily spot if something's wrong, and you're just 2 keypresses away from the right cursor position to select the entry you wanted.

Comment: Could you handle the rough edge by adding a `+` before the `?`  (Funny, I was thinking of `ex` mode, but I think this would work as well for normal mode.

Comment: What is `<Leader>` exactly?  (I can post a new question if it's hard to explain.)

Comment: See `:h Leader`. It's a key (actually, a string, but everyone just uses one character) to be used for mappings just as above. If you did not set it yourself, it defaults to "\", so `<Leader>f` is the same as `\f`. The distinct advantage of Leader over explicitly using a key is that everyone can just set the leader to what they find comfortable.